# Sum of reciprocals of finite odd numbers that add up to 1

Tags: number-theory, egyptian-fractions

I was reading a paper, and it claimed that only the divisors of an odd abundant number would satisfy this. Keep in mind that all divisors need not be used.
There doesn't seem to be a proof given, so is this true? And how would one prove it?

Paper's link: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X73901362

Comment: But every finite set of odd integers is a set of divisors of an odd abundant number.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I also realized the same thing a short while ago (but after I wrote my answer below), with this coming from every multiple of an abundant number being abundant and there being at least one odd abundant number (e.g., 945). Nonetheless, apart from odd perfect numbers (of which none are known to exist), the lcm of two or more odd, distinct integers where the sum of their reciprocals is $1$ must be an odd abundant number. Perhaps this number is what the authors intended instead of any existing odd abundant number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the base case of $x_1 = 1$ and $k = 1$, note $1$ is a divisor of all positive integers, including each odd [Abundant number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundant_number). With $k \ge 2$, it's fairly easy to show that all $x_i$ must also be divisors of an odd abundant number. We're given

$$\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{x_i} = 1 \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

where $x_i \lt x_j$ for all $i \lt j$ and all $x_i$ are odd integers. If the lcm of the $x_i$ is not an odd perfect number or they don't include all factors of the lcm apart from $1$, then I can multiply both sides by the lcm value to prove the result. However, although there are no known odd perfect numbers ([Odd perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) says any such number must be $\gt 10^{1500}$, have at least $101$ prime factors and at least $10$ distinct prime factors, etc.), just in case, plus to keep things simpler, multiply both sides by $\prod_{j=1}^k x_j$ instead to get

$$\sum_{i=1}^k \left(\prod_{j=1,j \neq i}^k x_j\right) = \prod_{j=1}^k x_j = a \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

Since $x_i$ times each $i$'th left side term gives $a$, and $x_i \neq x_j$ for $i \neq j$, each left side term is a unique factor of $a$. As the terms sum to $a$, but don't include all of the factors (e.g., $1$ and $a$ itself are not included), this means the sum of all of the factors of $a$ must be larger than itself, i.e., $a$ is an odd abundant number, with the odd part coming from all $x_i$ being odd.

Update: As [Gerry Myerson](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8269/gerry-myerson) stated in the question comments, and as I explained further, all finite sets of odd integers are a set of divisors of an odd abundant number, with this being due to there being at least one odd abundant number (e.g., $945$) and every multiple of an abundant number being abundant. Thus, perhaps the author was referring to a specific odd abundant number, with this most likely being either the lcm of the $x_i$ or the product of them, i.e., $a$ in \eqref{eq2}.

Comment: Why does it only work for odd numbers though? For example 28 is not an abundant number but $\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{4}+ \frac{1}{7}+ \frac{1}{14} + \frac{1}{28} = 1$

Comment: @Nimish Actually, it works also for $x_i$ which can be even numbers being factors of an even abundant number. With your example, note that $2$, $4$, $7$, $14$ and $28$ are also all divisors of the even abundant number of $56$, as indicated in the Wikipedia page. $28$ is a special case of being a perfect number.  If the denominator used is the lcm of all of the $x_i$, you can show the values can also be of a perfect number (but not a deficient number). Note there are no known odd perfect numbers (perhaps why paper used only odd numbers), but there's no proof yet that no such numbers exist.

Answer (score 0):

When you say that all of the divisors don't have be used, I believe what you are making reference to are *pseudoperfect numbers*; i.e., positive integers that are equal to the sum of some of their divisors.

For example, consider

$$ 945 = 315 + 189 + 135 + 105 + 63 + 45 + 35 + 27 + 15 + 9 + 7 .$$

Now, if we divide both sides by 945, we get

$$ 1 = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{15} + \frac{1}{21} + \frac{1}{27} + \frac{1}{35} + \frac{1}{63} \frac{1}{105} + \frac{1}{135}. $$

It's not hard to see that this will happen with every pseudoperfect number.